# Better way to create an Events table?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert, event-notification

I working on a medium sized `PostgreSQL` database with some schemas, each with some tables.

In almost every schema there are tables that represent event tables, where something that has "happened to" or was "caused by" a user is inserted. Essentially making each row in those tables an "Event".

Since I need users (and not necessarily the inserting user) to be able to find Events that have happened *since they checked last*, I am looking for some way of taking rows inserted into those tables (different table name and schemas) and adding them into an "Events" table.

The `Events` table will have a `UUID` as `PK`, and a `UUID` indicating what user "owns" (caused) the event to happen. Then comes the information from the table representing the "Event".

My original plan was to have a `INSERT` trigger, for the tables representing the events, that inserted a new row in the `Events` table with the original insert.

[image: Insertion with trigger]

Of course I would also need some kind of `UPDATE` trigger so that any updates made to the original row (in the original table) is also made to the row in the `Events` table, but this could just as well be a deletion of the original row (in the `Events` table) and then insertion of the new row.

The question is two-fold:

- 1. **Is there a better way for me to have a "Events since last checked" function? (Without implementing a horrific amount of booleans and checks and timestamps.)**
- 2. **What is the best way to insert the necessary information from the separate tables, with different names, layouts and schemas, into the `Events` table?**